# Jupyter Notebook: How to improve navigation experience over long page

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I would like to be able to switch rapidly from one section of my Jupyter notebook to another section, I mean within the same .ipynb file, as these files tend to get long while exploring data.

Ideally, this will be possible by marking the scrollbar of the navigator. I was thinking using a mozilla firefox add-ons, like "Scrollbar Search Highlighter" or "Content Scrollbar", but I didn't find a way to use them within the Jupyter notebook context.

Any idea to improve Jupyter notebook experience related to long page navigation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jupyter notebook extensions [(link)](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions) come with the [Table of Contents](http://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nbextensions/toc2/README.html) extension, which allows you to conveniently navigate over the various sections of your notebook

Comment: Actually, this is what I was looking for, and I was not aware of the development of those notebook extensions. Thank you Stelios for the hint.

Answer (score 1):

Make use of [nbextensions](https://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html). From there you can enable Table of contents which finally look like this:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwvqa.png]

Comment: thank you @Aravind, I think at that time this extension was not available.

Answer (score 1):

Table of contents is built-in JupyterLab by default now:
https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/toc.html

Also available as the structure tab of DataSpell and Pycharm:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/dataspell/guided-tour-around-the-user-interface.html#tool-windows